# bower install take repo, not specific files in main

Tags: bower

I am trying to install some js files via bower. My repo has a bower.json with a main property, however the whole repo gets installed to components/, not just the files in the dist/custom/ dir.

Here is what my bower.rc looks like

```
    {
        "name": "jquery-m",
        "version": "2.0.2mup",
        "description": "Meetup custom build of jQuery 2.0, used on mobile",
        "main": [ "./dist/custom/" ],
        "license": "MIT"
    }
```

Is this the way bower is supposed to work? I thought it was possible just to specify certain files with your main property.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is how Bower is meant to work. [Bower-installer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bower-installer) looks like a more lightweight solution than Grunt to solve the exact requirement you're describing and get just the files you need to be deployed to production.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how Bower works.

It always look for the matching tag on the repo; if cannot find one, it goes with the default branch, and download it.

The unique usage I've seen so far for the `main` property of a `bower.json` file is for integration, for example with build tools, like [Grunt](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-bower-requirejs) (there are lots of other bower related tasks, just Google around) and others.

Comment: Package authors can use the `ignore` property to ignore unneeded files.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered this a few days ago, after I gived this answer; I wasn't up-to-date with bower features

Answer (score 0):

This is a common misconception.

As stated in Bower documentation, the `main` property is a string/array listing *the primary endpoints of your package*.

Bower package maintainers (and maybe users, [using the `overrides` property](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/585)) can use the `ignore` property, which is *an array of paths not needed in production that you want Bower to ignore when installing your package*.

Example:

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "ignore": [
    "test/**",
    ".jshintrc"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "foo": "~1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, what ``overrides`` option? ``Bower`` is a glorified git client, get used to that. Ah I forgot, even git can bring down dependencies i.e. submodules. lol