# Bower - should I create a separate repository for bower and for development?

Tags: bower

Is it possible to have only one repository that would be "installable" from bower?

Currently I have registered a bower package that is connected to the development repository, but when running `bower install` I want only the `dist` files to be downloaded.

I have seen people keeping two repositories - 1st for development and 2nd as a bower package repo.

Is this the desired solution - or is it possible to have a single repo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered something very close to this some hours ago: [bower install take repo, not specific files in main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057038/bower-install-take-repo-not-specific-files-in-main/17057105#17057105)

You cannot install just "some" files from a repo. That's not how Bower works - it will **always** download all files from the tag/branch.

I personally think that's okay to download everything, because this will happen only once. And you can read the `main` property from the Bower manifest file (bower.json).

However, if you really want to download only dist files, a very easy thing to do is:

- Keep your development code in an non-default branch;
- Keep your dist code in the default branch to be installed via Bower (this probably is `master`)

Of course, do not forget that tags should be generated on top of that branch then.

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of bower offer the `ignore` property:

> ignore [array]: An array of paths not needed in production that you want Bower to ignore when installing your package.

That means, all package authors have to create a bower.json file.